# Xamarin Android SQLite cascade insert exception

Tags: sqlite, insert, xamarin.android, cascade

I would like to add some data to my Sqlite database with SqlLiteNetExtensions but it fails on this line and throws an unhandled exception:

```
SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions.WriteOperations.InsertWithChildren(GetConnection(), HeaderDB, recursive: true);
```

My `GetConnection` method looks like this:

```
public SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
{
    var sqliteFilename = "SQLiteEx.db3";
    string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); // Documents folder

    var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, sqliteFilename);
    Console.WriteLine(path);

    if (!File.Exists(path)) 
        File.Create(path);

    var plat = new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid();
    var conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(plat, path);

    return conn;
}
```

All I do is this: **(Edit: Add more code)**

```
bool isReachable = await isReach();

        if (!isReachable)
        {
            listDataChild["myChild"].Add("something");
            listAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

            GetConnection().CreateTable<HeaderDB>();
            GetConnection().CreateTable<ChildDB>();

            var HeaderDB = new HeaderDB
            {
                Bezeichnung = "Foo",
                ChildDB = new List<ChildDB>
            {
                new ChildDB {Bezeichnung = "blah", IpAdresse = "blah"}

            }
            };

            SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions.WriteOperations.InsertWithChildren(GetConnection(), HeaderDB, recursive: true);
        }
```

in my isReach i got:

```
Task<bool> isReach()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            EditText etIpAdress = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.editText2);

            var IpArray = etIpAdress.Text.Split('.');
            var myIpAdress = new byte[4];

            int i = 0;
            foreach (string s in IpArray)
            {
                myIpAdress[i] = Convert.ToByte(s);
                i++;
            }

            var ping = new Ping();

            var reply = ping.Send(new IPAddress(myIpAdress), 3500);
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
```

In my "domain" classes I got this:

```
    [Table("Parent")]
    public class HeaderDB
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ChildId { get; set; }
        public string Description{ get; set; }
        [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeInsert)]
        public List<ChildDB> ChildDB { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and this:

```
[Table("Child")]
    public class ChildDB
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(typeof(HeaderDB))]
        public int HeaderId { get; set; }
        public string Bezeichnung { get; set; }
        public string IpAdresse { get; set; }
        [ManyToOne]
        public HeaderDB HeaderDB { get; set; }
    }
```

Hope that someone knows whats going on

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue, my `SQLiteNetExtensions` version is 1.3.0, my emulator's version is android 6.0. What is the exception? Just unhandled exception? No detail information?

Comment: Im afraid no detail information. Before I create my tables I check one condition in a method, which is executed in another thread (async await) but thats should not affect my insert I hope.

Comment: Then maybe you can share more code? By the way, I changed the `Description` in code `new ChildDB { Description= "blah", IpAdresse = "blah" }` to `Bezeichnung`, cause you don't have a property named `Description` in class `ChildDB`.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I forgot to translate my propertys in english. Will post more code in couple of hours

Comment: So because I got this message from VisualStudiio: "Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code)." I moved my Insert Code in my onButtonSave Method and now it shows me a more useful exception: "Unhandled Exception:

SQLiteNetExtensions.Exceptions.IncorrectRelationshipException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details> occurred" But why is my relationship incorrect, dont get it.

Comment: Checked again with your table, I didn't see incorrect relationship either...

Comment: thanks anyway! will post a solution, when its done and works